# Setting encoding and Content-Type for Wiktionary API call

Tags: php, character-encoding, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I have setup this Wiktionary API call, but I can't figure out what is the encoding of data. I know the container is json, but I can't figure out the value of the internal string.

http://ru.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=parse&prop=wikitext&page=%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F

PHP Code:

```
$str = file_get_contents('http://ru.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=parse&prop=wikitext&page=%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F');
$str = json_decode($str,true);

header('Content-type: UTF-8');
$a = $str['parse']['wikitext']['*'];
echo $a;
```

I can't find anything in their help files. It should be Russian letters ex.

```
= {{-ru-}} =

=== Морфологические и синтаксические свойства ===
{{гл ru 2a-сяСВ
|основа=обра́дова
|основа1=обра́ду
|слоги={{по-слогам|об|ра́|до|вать|ся}}
|соотв=радоваться
}}

{{морфо|об|рад|ова|ть|ся}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8');
```

instead of your

```
header('Content-type: UTF-8');
```

### The code..

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8');
$str = file_get_contents('http://ru.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=parse&prop=wikitext&page=%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F');
$str = json_decode($str,true);
$a = $str['parse']['wikitext']['*'];
echo $a;
```

**`OUTPUT:`**

> = {{-ru-}} = === Морфологические и синтаксические свойства === {{гл ru 2a-сяСВ |основа=обра́дова |основа1=обра́ду
>   |слоги={{по-слогам|об|ра́|до|вать|ся}} |соотв=радоваться }}
>   {{морфо|об|рад|ова|ть|ся}} === Произношение === {{transcription|}}
>   {{медиа|Ru-обрадоваться.ogg}} === Семантические свойства === ====
>   Значение ==== # [[испытать]], [[почувствовать]] [[радость]]
>   {{пример|}} # # ==== Синонимы ==== # # # ==== Антонимы ==== #
>   [[огорчиться]], [[опечалиться]], [[расстроиться]]; [[загрустить]] # #
>   ==== Гиперонимы ==== # # # ==== Гипонимы ==== # [[возликовать]], [[возрадоваться]] # # === Родственные слова === {{родств-блок
>   |имена-собственные= |существительные=[[радость]]
>   |прилагательные=[[обрадованный]]; [[рад]]; [[радостный]]
>   |глаголы=[[обрадовать]]; [[радовать]], [[радоваться]],
>   [[возрадоваться]], [[порадовать]], [[порадоваться]]
>   |наречия=[[обрадованно]], [[радостно]] }} === Этимология ===
>   {{-ся|[[обрадовать]]}} из [[об-]] + [[радовать]] ([[рад]]), далее от
>   {{этимология:рад|да}} === Фразеологизмы и устойчивые сочетания === ===
>   Перевод === {{перев-блок| |abq= |ab= |av= |ave= |agh= |aja= |ady= |az=
>   |ay= |ain= |ain.kana= |ain.lat= |sq= |als= |ale= |alt= |en=[[be
>   glad]]; [[be happy]]; [[rejoice]] |ar= |an= |arc.jud= |arc.syr= |arn=
>   |hy= |asm= |ast= |af= |bar= |bm= |eu= |ba= |be=[[узрадавацца]],
>   [[абрадавацца]], [[усцешыцца]] |bn= |bg= |bs= |br= |bua= |cy= |wa=
>   |hu= |vep= |hsb= |vot= |vo= |wo= |vro= |vi= |gag= |haw= |ht= |gl= |ze=
>   |kl= |el= |ka= |gn= |gu= |gd= |dar= |prs= |da= |dv= |ang= |grc= |sgs=
>   |zza= |zu= |he= |yi= |io= |id= |ia= |iu= |ik= |ga= |is= |es= |it=
>   |kbd= |kk= |xal= |kn= |kaa= |krc= |krl= |ca= |csb= |qu= |ky= |zh=
>   |zh-tw= |zh-cn= |kom= |koi= |kok= |kw= |ko= |co= |xh= |crh= |ku= |km=
>   |lad= |lo= |la= |lez= |lv= |li= |ln= |lt= |lb= |mk= |mg= |ms= |ml=
>   |mt= |mi= |chm= |mdf= |mo= |mn= |gv= |nv= |gld= |nah= |na= |nio= |nap=
>   |de= |yrk= |nl= |dsb= |no= |oc= |os= |pa= |pap= |fa= |pl= |pt= |ps=
>   |pms= |rap= |rm= |ro= |sjd= |sa= |sc= |se= |sr= |sr-c= |sr-l= |scn=
>   |sk= |sl= |slovio-c= |slovio-l= |so= |chu.cyr= |chu.glag= |sw= |tab=
>   |tl= |tg= |ty= |th= |ta= |tt= |tt.cyr= |tt.lat= |te= |art= |tpi= |kim=
>   |tn= |tyv= |tr= |tk= |udm= |ug= |uz= |uk=[[зрадіти]] (кому-чому, з
>   чого), [[порадуватися]], [[порадіти]] (з кого-чого, кому-чому),
>   [[потішитися]], [[утішитися]], [[втішитися]] (чим) |ur= |fo= |fi= |fr=
>   |fy= |fur= |kjh= |ha= |hi= |hr= |rom= |ce= |cs= |cv= |sv= |cjs= |sco=
>   |ewe= |myv= |eo= |et= |jv= |sah= |ja= }} === Библиография === *
>   {{unfinished |m= |p=1 |s= |e= }} [[Категория:Глаголы эмоций]]
>   [[Категория:Радость]] {{длина слова|12}} [[fr:обрадоваться]]
>   [[vi:обрадоваться]]